# 30 Second Timeout PHP - Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to run this loop:

```
while ($serv = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$service."'")) {
   $serv_desc = $serv['serv_desc'];
}
```

`serv_id` is just a number.

`$service` is a number from `$_POST`

`serv_desc` is a description of the service - perhaps a word or two.

Why does it keep timing out?

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\globaldetroit\display.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an infinite loop! You're repeatedly executing the query forever.

Try this:

```
// Added intval() to prevent SQL injection and standardized variable names ($result)
$sql = "select serv_desc from service where serv_id='" . intval( $service) . "'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$serv_desc = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) 
{
   $serv_desc[] = $row['serv_desc'];
}
```

Comment: You willy probably want `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead - it's slightly faster.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - Updated, thanks! Just curious, how do you know it's faster / by how much? Is it because `mysql_fetch_array` is returning both a numerical and associative indexed array, while `mysql_fetch_assoc` is strictly associative?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. The time difference is really small, but it does take twice the amount of memory which can be a major difference if you're getting 50KB BLOB fields (such as images) from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your code reads like this:

> Can i create a new query? If i can, do it again

You should do it like this (i also added protection against SQL injection):

```
$query = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($service)."'");
while ($serv = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $serv_desc = $serv['serv_desc'];
}
```

Comment: You are so right, I am so stupid today! I know this. Just tired eyes after two straight days looking at this display interface!

Comment: You should try rubberducking, its awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because I it is a endless loop due mysql_query always returns resource. 
try this instead.

```
$servRes = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$service."'");
while ($serv = mysql_fetch_array($servRes, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $serv_desc = $serv['serv_desc'];
}
```

It works but when you only have one record to go trough I would make it without while loop. It's not needed then.

Comment: Not true, `mysql_query` will return false on failure (i.e. not a resource).

Comment: I know but here it always returned resource. Otherwise it would not be infinte loop.